# Google Wallet Server Communication With .net core API

Tags: c#, google-developers-console, android-pay, core-api

I am generating a test Pass using google wallet and APi and integrating with my .net core .
I am having trouble that how my server will know if user adds the passes to wallets or removes it 
what steps should i follow.
May i want to know Google server call my localhost machine API automatically and it is accurated?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ReceiveNotification()
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            var notificationContent = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

            if (await ValidateWebhookAsync(notificationContent))
            {
                // Process the notification content here

                // For example, log the notification
                LogNotification(notificationContent);

                // Return a success response
                return Ok();
            }
            else
            {
                // Validation failed, return an error response
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
    }
```